# typescript and express js. change res json `Response` type

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, type-declaration

in typescript, I am trying to overwrite the express's `Response` `json` object to be a specific type of object to always be used

for example, I want to enforce a interface type that would error out if the following format was not followed

```
  return res.status(200).json({
    data: ["a", {"a": "b"}],
    success: true,
  });
```

I attempted to use `dts-gen --m express -f src/types/express.d.ts` to create the declaration file to modify but it ended in failure.

is there a way to overwrite a specific type on an existing library or do I need to create a declaration file specific to my needs?

Comment: `express` is notorious for being not that typeable. It's best to avoid using a lot of custom middleware and to keep well-typed code apart from `express` routing code, if you choose to keep using this library.

Comment: good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
interface Json {
  success: boolean;
  data: any[];
}

type Send<T = Response> = (body?: Json) => T;

interface CustomResponse extends Response {
  json: Send<this>;
}
```

I was able to create a new interface that extended this. just needed to learn a bit more :) hopefully this can help out someone else!

Comment: missed then add to ```export const example = asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: CustomResponse, next: NextFunction) => {```

Answer (score 5):

You can set custom types in generic types of `req` and `res` objects such a:

```js
import type * as E from 'express';

interface CustomResponseType {
  test: string;
}

export default async function Example(
  req: E.Request<undefined, CustomResponseType, [CustomReqBodyType?], [CustomReqQueryType?]>,
  res: E.Response<CustomResponseType>
): Promise<E.Response<CustomResponseType, Record<string, any>>> {
  return res.status(200).json({ test: 'success' });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just an extend reply, if you want to explicit define type for response, you can do like this

```js
// overlap the ResBody = any (from Express module) to the exact type 
// you want in CustomResponse

type Send<ResBody = any, T = Response<ResBody>> = (body?: ResBody) => T;

export interface CustomResponse<T> extends Response {
   json: Send<T, this>
}
```

then you can import in the controller function:

`async (req: Request, res: CustomResponse<IUser>, next: NextFunction) =>`

Your `res.json()` will strictly stick to the `IUser` Interface.